# How to make the height of a div shrink as much as possible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I've got a header menu which I'm trying to make responsive using CSS flex.

The flex functionality works fine, but the height of the items are always huge for some reason.

The code I'm using is below (the borders are just there to show the elements heights).

The height of the title `<div>` should shrink to match that of the `<p>` element. Anybody know how to do this?

```css
#header {
    background: #526272;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height:auto;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
}

html {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-right: solid red;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

p {
    border-right: solid blue;
}

#menuBar {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}

#social {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="title"><p>EXAMPLE SITE NAME</p></div>
    <div id="menuBar"><p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="social"><p>Socials</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `padding: 1em` on the `div.title` container. That creates a lot of space on all four sides.

Try this instead:

```
.title { padding: 0 1em; } /* padding only on the left and right */
```

Also, `p` elements come with default margins set by the browser. Make this adjustment:

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

```css
#header {
  background: #526272;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1em;  /* adjusted */
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-right: solid red;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0;  /* new */
  border-right: solid blue;
}
#menuBar {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#social {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <p>EXAMPLE SITE NAME</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menuBar">
    <p>Menu</p>
  </div>
  <div id="social">
    <p>Socials</p>
  </div>
</div>
```